How to handle select with big number of options in Vue3 using Virtual Scrolling?
I'm using Virtual Scrolling with vue3-virtual-scroll-list to handle 50,000 options (like locations).
The VirtualList component renders only the visible items in the viewport.
The :keeps prop determines how many items are rendered at a time.
:data-sources contains the list of items to render.
LocationItem is a reusable component that renders each item in the list.
The filterLocations method dynamically updates the filteredLocations array based on the search query.
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      v-model="searchQuery"
      @input="filterLocations"
      placeholder="Search locations"
      class="search-input"
    />
    <virtual-list
      :data-key="'id'"
      :data-sources="filteredLocations"
      :data-component="LocationItem"
      :keeps="20"
      tag="div"
      class="virtual-list"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import VirtualList from "vue3-virtual-scroll-list";

const LocationItem = defineComponent({
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Object, 
      required: true, 
    },
  },
  template: `<div class="list-item">{{ data.name }}</div>`,
});

export default {
  components: { VirtualList },
  data() {
    return {
      locations: Array.from({ length: 50000 }, (_, i) => ({
        id: i + 1,
        name: `Location ${i + 1}`,
      })),
      filteredLocations: [],
      searchQuery: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.filteredLocations = this.locations;
  },
  methods: {
    filterLocations() {
      const query = this.searchQuery.toLowerCase();
      this.filteredLocations = this.locations.filter(location =>
        location.name.toLowerCase().includes(query)
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>

I get the following warning: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode.

It's unknown where the warning comes from. What did make you think the problem is related to the amount of options? Did you try to make it smaller until the warning disappears? The use of template string in LocationItem requires a build with runtime compiler at least. You don't use LocationItem anywhere in script, it's not exposed to the template, could be a problem
